# How to call resolve after a promise is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, q

I have a dialog has radio buttons and confirm button.
we don't know what function is called until the confirm button is clicked.\

So I create a object to reference callback functions as below.

```
var context = {
 callback: undefined;
 resolve: undefined;
 reject: undefined;
}

dialog.open = function(callback){
 context.callback = callback;
 
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  context.resolve = resolve;
  context.reject = reject;
 }) 
}
```

The confirm function likes this;

```
function confirm () {
 if(radio.value === "test") callA();
 else callB();
}

function callA() {
  context.callback("A");
  context.resolve("A");
}

function callB() {
  context.callback("B");
  context.resolve("B");
}
```

And I call dialog.open()

```
dialog.open((res) => {
 console.log(res)
}).then((res) => {
 console.log(res)
})
```

I clicked the confirm button multiple times for testing.
The callback is called whenever clicking, but the resolve(then) is called one time..

Is it possible to promise.then works like callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the confirm button first time, confirm() will be invoked and as a result context.callback() and context.resolve() will be invoked. When context.resolve() gets invoked it resolves the promise i.e. changes its internal state from pending to resolved. 
Now, on subsequent clicks of the confirm button same thing happens but since the promise is already resolved (by first click) even though context.resolve() gets invoked nothing happens.
As for then(), it accepts a callback function as an argument. This callback function is called asynchronously when the promise resolves or rejects(first time only). You can go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then for a detailed explanation of how then() works.

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I searched this issue so far, I concluded the mechanism of Promise doesn't support what I want.